# MySQL datetime datatype get total number of visitors on a specific date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have this kind of entries in my database table:

[image]

In the Web Application that i'm creating, I am letting users select a custom dates range, so for example, one user would select a date range from `2014-05-13` to `2014-05-15`. I want to get the total number of `nVisitors` for each day using MySQL.

If you noticed that `2014-05-13` date has a time, so I want to get the total of nVistors of per day depending on the date range the user selected on my web app.

An example output would be:

```
   Date    |   total
2014-05-13 |    146
2014-05-14 |    200
2014-05-15 |    150
```

Given that the total column was a result of the nVisitors per day that the user has selected.

Any ideas please. Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
select date(`date`), sum(total) from yourtable 
where date(`date`) between date('2014-05-13') and date('2014-05-15') 
group by date(`date`)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I think that will only output a sum column, it will not get the sum per day. Look at my sample output on my question :)

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower:- Updated my answer to get the result per day! Hope that helps :)

Comment: May be it should be `select date(`date`), sum(total) from yourtable ...` ?

Comment: @sri:- Indeed but I emphasised more on the range part as I thought thats what OP is looking for. However I have update my answer. Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 1):

Try Below:

```
select DATE(date) as Date,count(idStoreVisitor) as Total from yourTable where Date(date) >= <User_inputDateRange1> 
and Date(date)<= <User_inputDateRange2> group by Date(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the day interval in your query.

```
select count(*) from <table> where last_login > (curdate() - interval 30 day) order by <date column> desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer guys, because of you guys, I had an idea how to approach this problem.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "select DATE(date),sum(nVisitors) from 
  store_visitors where `date` between 
  '$startDate 00:00' and '$endDate 23:59' group by DATE(date)";
```

I added a 00:00 and a 23:59 at the end of the date range since the data type of my columns are `datetime`.

Thanks again! :)

Comment: You need to add backticks on your date column else it will fail. Thanks :)